# How can I prevent the effervescence of a solvent during evaporation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, solvents

How can I prevent the effervescence of a solvent like petroleum ether when I evaporate it on a water bath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break a ceramic utensil (mug, plate, any porous item will do) and add a few chips in the solution. This should lead to a smoother boil rather than the liquid jumping around.

This is a cheap alternative of anti bumping granules and works in a similar way by allowing the gas to accumulate on the rough surface and escape the solvent in a controlled fashion.